# Basic Python TCP Socket Server & Client

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

My first question here, please be gentle :)  I'm trying to setup a basic Python (2.7) TCP socket server that is multithreaded (I haven't got to the multithreaded part yet), and a client.

Here is the server:

```
# Basic TCP socket server

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = ''
port = 8888

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to %s" % addr)
    c.send("Hello socket")
    c.close()
```

And here is the client:

```
# Basic TCP socket client

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8888

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)

s.close()
```

When I run the server it seems to execute without errors, but when I run the client to connect, I don't see the message that should be printed out to my terminal window where server is running.  Here is the error (as @Rawing pointed out):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "server.py", line 19, in
>   
>       print("Connected to %s" % addr) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

As far as making the server multithreaded, I need to read up on that but any suggestions are welcome.

Thank You.

Comment: RE multithreading a server: read up on ZeroMQ. It's an attempt to make socket programming more human friendly. It's old and probably over-complex for someone who just wants to learn, BUT: the documentation is superb and explains the pitfalls that you may fall into with normal socket programming in python and how to overcome them, both in theory and with ZeroMQ.

Comment: Works fine on my machine - if the message you expected to be printed is `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that `c.close` does *absolutely nothing* - you have to write `c.close()` to actually call the method.

Comment: As the above commenter says, this does try to do the print and then falls over. Is it possible you're doing something odd wrt. the terminal setup to prevent the server's stdout from flushing correctly when the connection is made?

Comment: Please copy-paste into your question the actual output you see when you run these programs.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code

- Your use of the string-formatting operator `%` is incorrect in your server program. If you pass a tuple to `%` (and `addr` is a tuple), then each item in the tuple must match one formatting directive. This is why your server program is failing.

  ```
  print("Connected to %s" % str(addr))
  ```
- In both programs, you mention, but do not invoke, `socket.close`. Try these in the appropriate locations:

  ```
  s.close()
  c.close()
  ```

Comment: Note: OP edited the question to add parentheses to the `socket.close` lines. In the original question, the lines looked like `s.close` and `c.close`.

Comment: Should I have edited my original post with updates to code or do a new reply with code updates?  I thought I had read in the guidelines it was preferred to update original comment.

Comment: I fixed the syntax for `socket.close` so they are invoked, and used your print function...now it works.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of a TCP server in python 3 (If you are willing to use it instead of 2.7)

**Server:**

```
import socketserver

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.rfile.readline() # Receive data from client
        self.wfile.write(new_data) # Send data to client


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

**Client:**

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT)) # Connect
    sock.sendall(bytes(data + "\n", "utf-8")) # Send data
    received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8") # Receive data synchronically
```

Answer (score -1):

`bind` the server to an ip, eg: `host='127.0.0.1`, and it should work.

Update: I'm totally wrong. I fixed a few things in your scripts and assumed that was the issue, but it's not - as the reply below states, binding to ('', ) is perfectly valid.

Looks like your socket code is perfectly good, but falls over the print statement. I fixed it with `print("Connected to {}".format(addr))`

Comment: Binding to `''` is perfectly valid. It is shorthand for `INADDR_ANY`. See, for example, [this example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example)